# What is the point of writing WCF Interceptors, compared to using a helper method?

Tags: design

For those of you who don't know, WCF allows you to attach interceptors to methods in the service contract.  The interceptor is capable of performing custom logic before and after a method call, and is (as far as I know) used mainly for validating parameters and doing custom authorization schemes.

But what's the point of using them if you can just write a helper method to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It enables the [open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), which is the 'O' in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).  It states that modules should be open for extension, but closed for modification.  Essentially, interceptors allow you to extend the behavior of a method call by adding new code, instead of by changing existing code, as you would have to do to add a call to a helper method.

A lot of very smart people have written in detail about why this is beneficial, but the bottom line is it makes your program less prone to breaking old features when you add new features.

Answer (score 2):

MSDN [has a good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744837(v=vs.110).aspx) of using Interceptors for implementing user security:

```
// Define a query interceptor for the Orders entity set.
[QueryInterceptor("Orders")]
public Expression<Func<Order, bool>> OnQueryOrders()
{
    // Filter the returned orders to only orders  
    // that belong to a customer that is the current user. 
    return o => o.Customer.ContactName ==
        HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: So what is the benefit over, say, using a helper method?

Comment: The same benefits that you have any time you use an attribute instead of a helper method, I would imagine. Lower coupling, higher code cohesion.  You also get the benefits that an event-based system has.

Comment: This is automatic, a helper method, when you call it, can do the same thing, but if you forget to call it, you won't get the functionality. The interceptor methods are 'set and forget', they always get called, so you don't have to worry about whether they're called or not, which is kind of a big deal with e.g. security ;)